# Is it possible to set the minimum value of a margin set by a percentage using CSS?

Tags: css, web

What I want to accomplish is very similar to what the `min-width` attribute does for width values.

I want to be able to set a margin value by a percentage up to a point, and then switch over to a concrete predefined pixel value. So the margin would be `margin-left: 20%;` and then I would have a `min-value: 100px`.

Is this possible, and if not with CSS, what sorts of workarounds are there?

Comment: Look into media queries, especially, `@media screen and (max-width: ...` which allows you to use different CSS when the screen width gets smaller.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: @VincentMcNabb Could you add the `@media screen` idea as an answer? That is the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use media queries to achieve your goal.

If you have a `div` that takes up most of the screen, except for the 20% margin on the left, and you want that margin to be no less than 100px, then you can use a media query to set the margin to 100px when the frame width becomes less than 500px (20% of 500px is 100px).

If your HTML is this

```
<body>
    <div class="left-margin">
        My left margin is 20% unless that would become less than 100px, in which
        case, my left margin would become 100px.
    </div>
</body>
```

Then your CSS could look like this

```
body, html
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.left-margin
{
    margin-left: 20%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px)
{
    .left-margin
    {
        margin-left: 100px;
    }
}
```

This basically means that everything inside the media query is only applied with frame widths of 500px or less. When the screen width becomes larger than 500px, the contents of the media query are ignored, and the margin becomes 20%.

http://jsfiddle.net/5g16xbtg/

Answer (score 0):

Try stick an empty div with with width set by % and min-width by px. Just put in on before the element that you want to have a margin on. For example below.

```
<div style="position:relative; float:left; width:20%; min-width:100px">    
<div style="position:relative; float:left; margin:0">
```